# Windows Phone 7 dev: How Take audio files from phone memory

Tags: windows-phone-7

I wonder how i can take audio files from phone memory? and how put them in a list?

And finally how i can play them?

Thanks in advance...

ps. Can i "load" my emulator with some songs in order to try my app?

Answer (score 3):

There is a class called `MediaLibrary` that can help you with this.  Here's some sample code:

```
MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
SongsList.ItemsSource = library.Songs;
```

There are several other collections on MediaLibrary including Albums, Playlists, Genres, etc.

To get access to the `MediaLibrary` object, you have to add a reference to Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll - it's in the `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media` namespace.

See more information about `MediaLibrary` at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.aspx

Comment: There is more information on creating a background agent player from the Windows Phone 7 samples at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744(v=VS.92).aspx

Comment: Thank you... this "SongsList.ItemsSource = library.Songs;" gives me an error... What i do wrong?

Comment: You have to have SongsList defined (i.e. as a `ListBox` in the XAML for the page.) Look into the documentation further to get what you need

Comment: ok, it works, now do you know if i can (and how) put songs in my emulator in order to test it? Thanks..

Comment: I don't think you can do that. From what the SDK documentation and my own plunking around reveals, there is no "Add" method to Songs like there is to Photos. I'll keep looking, but I don't see any way to do it at present.